# AutoLayout UITableView Custom Cell Solution Needed

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I using AutoLayout for a UITableView with a custom cell.  The cell contains two UIViews.  The first view is longer then the second and contains text.  The second UIView hold an icon.

The first UIView (A) is pinned to the left side of the content view using Leading Space to superview(content view), the second UIView (B) is pinned to the right side using Trailing Space to superview.

On an iPhone 5 UIView (A) takes the majority of the display space and bumps up to UIView (B) with a small space in between, depicted below.

[image: Layout on iPhone 5]

On an iPhone 6/6s the space between UIView (A) and UIView (B) is large, shown below.

[image: Layout on iPhone 6/6s]

I would like UIView (A) to increase in width to fill the space while UIView (B) stays pinned to the right side.  Is there a way of doing this using AutoLayout?

Comment: Have you used `multiplier`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your view A

[image]

This is your view B

[image]

Give equal width to view A and then use multiplier
[image]

Your output should look something like this in iphone 4 and iphone 6 plus
[image]

Comment: You'll want to use the multipliers instead of a fixed width here to ensure the view renders appropriately on every screen. 71 pixels on an iPhone 5S is quite something, while on a 6S Plus, it's rather minimal.
Therefor, I don't think this should be the answer.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, I was stuck on this layout but could not find a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add width constraint to View B. Add Trailing Space constraint for View A to View B with needed value (5?)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add View A's trailing space to View B constraint. View B does not have to have a width constraint if it has intrinsic size. Otherwise you need add View B's width constraint.